# mjpeg HTML5 video doesn't stream with <video>

Tags: html, html5-video, mjpeg

I'm trying to display mjpeg live stream in HTML 5

With `<img>` tag -> no problem it shows the stream great, but, I need some events to be fired to indicate when the stream is properly displayed

For example:

```
<img src="url" />
```

With `<video>` tag -> I'm able to get those events, but I'm not able to play mjpeg stream

For example:

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" controls onerror="onError()">
    <source src=url>
</video>
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 9):

There is [no general support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Supported_video_formats) for MJPEG streams in any browser beyond the `img` element. MJPEG has [no official standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG#Disadvantages) and there exist many variations which could be problematic with the video element as to how to detect what is an error without supporting every/most variations.

For the image element I guess a compromise has been made to allow for more tolerance format-wise at the cost of not being able to analyze the stream properly.

The closest we get to monitor events with the `img` element is to listen to the `onload`, `onerror` and `onabort` events. Beyond that we are given no option.

You could look into transcoding solutions such as the free [VLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode) combined with [MediaTomb](http://mediatomb.cc/pages/transcoding) (allow piping VLC output) that can convert the MJPEG format to a different one on the fly as a possible workaround. An alternative to that is to consider a Flash based solution.