# How to play mjpeg as video not image?

Tags: html, video, mjpeg

I have mjpeg stream (generated by ffserver) and I consume this stream as image, like this:

```
<img src='http://localhost:8090/live.mjpg'>
```

Basically I can see video within `img` tag, however it is still an image for a browser -- I don't get any controls like stop/play.

Thus my question, is it possible to consume this stream via `video` tag to get the controls? I tried it (in Chrome) and I get empty controls box (no video content).

*I am not looking for cross-browser ancient compatibility, I am looking for consuming mjpeg video stream as video, not as animated image.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-browser solution for displaying MJPEG stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12966492/2710385)

Comment: @dylmye, thank you, but not even close, the other post is 7 years old and struggles with browser compability. This is not my problem, my problem is with `video` tag in order to get controls (this was out of scope of the linked question).

Comment: glad I could help with my answer but in terms of duplicates is this closer? [mjpeg HTML5 video doesn't stream with <video>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37240815/2710385)

Comment: @dylmye, yes, indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<video>` tag only supports the following mimetypes:

- video/webm
- video/ogg
- video/mp4 (firefox only?)

(source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats))

so you would need to convert the mjpg (`video/x-motion-jpeg`) to one of these. You might want to use [a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12966492/2710385).