# How do I stream python OpenCV output to HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, python, html, opencv, flask

I'm trying to make an web interface for my python OpenCV code using Flask,with the intent of using a canvas HTML element to draw a "crop area" to extract details from the frame stream.Following some examples I've found here on Stackoverflow I was able to stream the output of my OpenCV code to an img element, but not to the canvas nor the video element.
Python Code:(Minimal)

```
import cv2

from flask import Flask, render_template,Response

app = Flask(__name__)

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def gen():    

    while True:
        ret, image = video_capture.read()
        cv2.imwrite('t.jpg', image)
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
           b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + open('t.jpg', 'rb').read() + b'\r\n')
    video_capture.release()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Video streaming"""
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    return Response(gen(),
                mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video Streaming </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Live Video Streaming </h1>
        <img id="img" src = "{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you will have to learn JavaScript for this.

Comment: this question shows that <video> may not support `mjpeg` format so this will not work with `<video>` [mjpeg HTML5 video doesn't stream with <video>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239869/mjpeg-html5-video-doesnt-stream-with-video)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This HTML with JavaScript display stream on Canvas and in `<img>` at the same time.

For single static image it needs to run `onload()`. For stream `MJPEG` it needs to use `setInterval()` to redraw image periodically.

It works for me on `Chrome` but my `Firefox` displays only first frame on `Canvas`. I think I had this problem before. Probably it needed something more to work correctly but I don't remeber what was it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video Streaming </title>
</head>
<body>

    <div width="640px" height="480px" style="display:inline-block">
        <h1>Image</h1>
        <img id="img" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
    </div>

    <div width="640px" height="480px" style="display:inline-block">
        <h1>Canvas</h1>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="640px" height="480px"></canvas>
    </div>

<script >

    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "{{ url_for('video_feed') }}";

    // need only for static image
    //img.onload = function(){   
    //    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    //};

    // need only for animated image
    function refreshCanvas(){
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
    window.setInterval("refreshCanvas()", 50);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I found old information [mjpeg HTML5 video doesn't stream with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239869/mjpeg-html5-video-doesnt-stream-with-video)  and it seems `<video>` may not support `mjpeg` format so it may not works with this stream.

---

Full working code.

I use `render_template_string` instead of `render_template` so everyone can put all code in one file and test it.

```
import cv2
from flask import Flask, render_template, render_template_string, Response

app = Flask(__name__)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def gen():    
    while True:
        ret, image = video_capture.read()
        cv2.imwrite('t.jpg', image)
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
           b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + open('t.jpg', 'rb').read() + b'\r\n')
    video_capture.release()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Video streaming"""
    #return render_template('index.html')
    return render_template_string('''<html>
<head>
    <title>Video Streaming </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Image</h1>
        <img id="img" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Canvas</h1>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="640px" height="480px"></canvas>
    </div>

<script >
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "{{ url_for('video_feed') }}";

    // need only for static image
    //img.onload = function(){   
    //    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    //};

    // need only for animated image
    function refreshCanvas(){
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
    window.setInterval("refreshCanvas()", 50);

</script>

</body>
</html>''')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    return Response(gen(),
                mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, simple and concise!

Answer (score 5):

For future reference to anyone that bumps into this question,although the answer provided by @furas works as intended, I've found that for my usecase it is also possible to assign the output frame to the canvas background using CSS,allowing to display the video only,and draw freely on top of that.

### **HTML Code**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video Streaming </title>
</head>
<style>
    .myCanvas{
       background-image: url("{{ url_for('video_feed') }}"); 
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Live Video Streaming </h1>
        <img id="img" src = "{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
        <canvas class="myCanvas" height="600" width="480">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: worked perfectoooooo